# My question got "marked as duplicate", but it's not

Tags: support

I have asked a question, and somebody marked it, and linked it to another answer, but it's not the same problem. How do I "unmark" it?

Comment: The question in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079796/javascript-beginner-using-variables-in-if-else

Comment: It's questionable..

Comment: If it wasn't a dup, I would have tried very hard to find some other reason to close it.

Comment: Y'know, it doesn't seem like a variable variable question to me at all.  Nor does the associated duplicate actually do *anything* to help with addressing the answer.

Comment: This is hilarious!

Comment: Oh, the irony..

Answer (score -2):

Several people believe your question is a duplicate. If you believe it is not then you should edit the question to make it clearer. You should also explain why your question is not a duplicate.

Comment: It was hammered by a gold badge holder. But for what it's worth, I'd have done the same.

Comment: But it's not the same at all?  I want to know how i can take the answer from the input, and make something like this = answer.price and not how to call an object?

Comment: @PatrickKnudsen: You're asking if `i === "egg"`, if you can do `i.price` instead of `egg.price`, right? The linked duplicate explains why that doesn't work.

Comment: i know i'ts not working, thats why I'm asking how to get it to work? it's not very helpfull just to get the answer "no you can do that." what about "no, you do it like this..."

Comment: @PatrickKnudsen Your question here on Meta does not link to the question that was closed as a duplicate. You need to read the answer to "How to remove duplicate mark from my question?" (linked above) and do what it says.

Comment: the link is in the comment?

Comment: @PatrickKnudsen It is there now but only because Cerbus is a good person. The link is not in your question here. You need to improve your original question rather than wasting time by grumbling here on Meta.

Comment: it's been there over an hour so not just now. But please tell me how i explain it better than "I want to know how i can take the answer from the input, and make something like this = answer.price"